# How do I properly set the content view in AppCompatActivity?

Tags: android, android-appcompat, appcompatactivity

When I call the `setContentView(myView)` method in an `AppCompatActivity`, instead of setting it directly, it calls through to some sort of delegate which for some reason wraps it in some unneeded layouts. However, I need it to be a direct child of the decor view. I've already disabled the action bar and window title via theme, unfortunately that didn't help. If I do `((ViewGroup)getWindow().getDecorView()).addView(myView)` the app crashes immediately on launch when said delegate tries to do something with its unneeded layouts and finds my view instead of them. The worst part is that such a behavior is absolutely undocumented, I found that out myself while debugging trying to understand why does the system disregard `setFitsSystemWindows(true)` on my root content view (which is a `DrawerLayout`).

Is there any way to completely disable this behavior? If no, is there any way to use the system `Activity` class while using the appcompat layout inflater in order to support per-view themes on pre-Lollipop?

I don't support anything older than ICS and I use toolbars inside fragments (without setting them as action bars) so I don't actually need any of appcompat's activity-related stuff in my app; the only reason to extend `AppCompatActivity` for me was its layout inflater.

Comment: "The worst part is that such a behavior is absolutely undocumented" -- that is because nobody should be relying upon `setContentView()` having any particular relationship to the decor view, as that relationship itself is undocumented.

Comment: @CommonsWare okay, how am I then supposed to make my view appear behind the status bar if there are those undocumented layouts wrapped around it?

Comment: I have not yet played with http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.4.html#UI but I don't see how "those undocumented layouts" would necessarily interfere with it.

Comment: `DrawerLayout` already supports `fitsSystemWindows`; AppCompat certainly does not stop you from drawing under the status bar. Perhaps you should create a question centered around fixing that problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [AppCompatDelegate](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegate.html)? It's a helper that provides you with compat behavior without requiring you to extend AppCompatActivity. However, it may well apply same wrapping pattern to your layouts (haven't tried it myself), but anyway worth taking a look.

Comment: So I figured out that the main trick is to prevent the `AppCompatDelegateImplV7.ensureSubDecor()` method from being called. That's really easy with an Activity that only calls `delegate.installViewFactory()`. This way you get your views themed but it doesn't mess with your content view.